# PHP: Как вытаскивать содержимое узлов xml при заполнении документа Word средствами библиотеки PHPWord?

Tags: php, парсер, xml, phpword

Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Получаю в переменную $result xml выдачи Яндекса, отправляю сие безобразие в документ Word методами библиотеки PHPWord:

```
foreach ($tmp as $key => $value) {

    if (is_string($value)) {
        /*var_dump(substr($value, 21));*/
    $cut = $value;
   $output = 'https://yandex.ru/search/xml?user' . urlencode($cut) . 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';

    $result = file_get_contents($output);
     
    $section->addText($result);

       $objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');
       sleep(30);
   }
```

Общий xml в переменной $result вставляется.. Выглядит это вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но такой xml отрывок в документе мне, естественно, не нужен. Я пытаюсь вытащить содержимое отдельных узлов xml и вставить их также в word, без самих тегов, но PHPWord не хочет этого делать.. Что я делаю неправильно? Извлечь содержимое между отдельными тегами пробовал так:

1)

```
preg_match_all('|<title>(.+)</title>|', $result, $match);
$section->addText($match);
```

2. 

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
$section->addText($xml);
```

Ни тот, ни другой вариант не работает.. Вордовский файл создается, но остается пустым..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше пользоваться функционалом DOMDocument. См. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Вроде это: $xml = simplexml_load_string($result); также работает.. Формирует на основе xml объекты, чтобы к ним можно было обращаться. вот так: $section->addText($result->title). Простите мое невежество, если ошибаюсь. Если сделать simplexml_load_string($result);, что уже PHPWord с этим не работает.. Допустим, $section->addText($result->title) - не работает и $section->addText($result); не срабатывает..

Comment: Да, но в DOMDocument больше возможностей управления настройками вывода структуры DOM в текстовый (XML) формат. Я решал сходные вашими задачи просмотра и редактирования документов MSOffice 2007 и OpenOffice. Тогда и пришел к указанному выше решению.

Comment: Спасибо, я тут попробовал ваш вариант, только немного в другой реализации..     $result = file_get_contents($output);
 //       htmlspecialchars(
        $al = simplexml_load_string($result);
        print_r($al);

Comment: Действительно, получаешь DOM - я его успешно получил и потом можно легко вот так -> получать доступ к отдельным узлам..

Comment: Предвижу проблемы при выводе в Word, но, на худой конец, можно обратно в xml нужный результат засобачить..

Comment: Разобранный DOM сохраняется с помощью saveXML. Если вы берете имеющийся XML, загружаете его, находите нужные узлы с помощью DOMXPath, редактируете нужные узлы, а потом сохраняете, то проблем быть не должно.

Comment: Проблемы могут возникнуть только в формат Office 2003, т.к. внутренний формат там специфический. А с 2007 документ офиса это ZIP архив в котором собран весь контент в XML файлах и картинках. Всегда можно вытащить один файл из архива, модифицировать и вернут обратно.